# Write a file using apply_async

Tags: python, file, join, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing to write contents of terminology_list (a large list having 19 million elements) to a file. Since we don't care about the order, I tried to use apply_async:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def terminology_write(terminology, to_file):
    to_file.write(terminology.lower()+'\n')

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open('async_write_file.txt','w') as to_file:
        for term in terminology_list:
            pool.apply_async(terminology_write, args = (term,to_file,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Procedure can be executed but nothing recorded in async_write_file.txt. 
Do you know why this happend?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simply said: If you are writing to a file from several processes at the same time they will disturb each other.

Comment: You will need a single writer.

Comment: or since you are just using 4 workers. write them out to individual files.

Comment: I can see that you are just reading from a single file, What are you exactly trying to solve ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @neotrinity I was trying to filter phrases, I have a list of phrases(15millions) and corpus data(19million sentences), I'd like to find and record phrases that have appeared in corpus at least once. So I wrote a main function to filter phrases, and since the volume is enormous, I tried to directly write selected phrases to a file instead of making a list to store them before writing to a file. That's why I tried to use 4 writers.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you, now I got it. I've changed to use a callback function to write, it seems that only using a single writer can write properly.